$ {f}^{\prime }\left( \xi \right) = {2024}\left( {f\left( \xi \right) - f\left( 0\right) }\right) $

Let $f\left( x\right)$ be differentiable on  $\lbrack 0, 2\rbrack$ , ${f}^{\prime }\left( 1\right) = 0$, Prove that there exists  $\xi\in\left( {0, 2}\right)$ such that
\begin{aligned} {f}^{\prime }\left( \xi \right) = {2024}\left( {f\left( \xi \right) - f\left( 0\right) }\right) \end{aligned}

If $f(1)=0$, it is OK by considering $g(x)=e^{2024x}[f(x)-f(0)]$. But $f'(1)=0$ what then?
Taking $f(x)=(x-1)^2,(x-1)^3$, it seems that the problem is right.

Changing $f(x)$ to $f(x)-f(1)$ does not change the question. So you can assume that $f(1)=0$.

@geetha290krm the $[f(x)-f(0)]$ changes.

If $h(x)=f(x)-f(1)$ then $h(x)-h(0)=[f(x)-f(1)]-[f(0)-f(1)]=f(x)-f(0)$.

@geetha290krm So $f'(1)=0$ is superfluous?

@geetha290krm $h(1)=0$, but $h(0)$ is not $0$.
